# Does OS X supports HID over Gatt?

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We are developing a hardware device that implements BTLE profiles and already works fine with iOS.

Now, we are implementing HID over Gatt profile so that it can communicate with OS X. The final purpose is changing PowerPoint slides and that such of things.

My iMAC does not detect the device using Bluetooth assistant, but I can connect to it with LightBlue app, although I get no keyboard effect. That makes me think I would need drivers/code, even develop an app.

I would appreciate any point to start with.

Comment: This deck from WWDC 2013 seems to indicate that as of OSX 10.9 HID over GATT is not supported http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/.../700/700.pdf?dl=1  I haven't found anything on Yosemite

Answer (score 4):

I answer myself in case it could be useful for anybody. I've updated my iMAC to Mavericks 10.9.4 and the first quick test has worked properly. I previously had Mountain Lion and it did not work as I posted before.

@Paulw11, thanks for the link. I watched the video and if I'm not wrong, there is a statement  that HID over Gatt profile (HOGP) is available from iOS7 and OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Good to know - I just read the PDF, which didn't mention HID over GATT for OSX.

Comment: @maria According to my thought and research, If you need an OS layer interaction then we can go for HID itself. I think HID is the safe choice.